# daVinci Resolve: Split-clip shortcut on German keboard

Tags: davinci-resolve, keyboard-shortcut

What is the keyboard shortcut for split clip on German keyboards in daVinci Resolve 15 ?

While a clip was selected in the edit tab's timeline and the playhead was over it, I tried `Ctrl+\` (=`Strg+AltGr+ß`), `Crtl+ß` , `Ctrl+<` and `Ctrl+>` , but none of these worked.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this key simply doesn't work on German keyboards.

It's probably because you have to press Alt-Gr to get the "" sign on a German keyboard, and the software doesn't accept that additional key.

You can, however, redefine this function to another key. In contrast to some documentation, this cannot be found in the project settings, but directly in the first main menu entry "DaVinci Resolve|Keyboard Customization".

[image]

You can search for *split* there and choose the command in the *timeline* group:

[image]